# when to use na.omit versus complete.cases

Tags: r

I have following code comparing na.omit and complete.cases:

```
> mydf
  AA BB
1  2  2
2 NA  5
3  6  8
4  5 NA
5  9  6
6 NA  1
> 
> 
> na.omit(mydf)
  AA BB
1  2  2
3  6  8
5  9  6
> 
> mydf[complete.cases(mydf),]
  AA BB
1  2  2
3  6  8
5  9  6
> 
> str(na.omit(mydf))
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ AA: int  2 6 9
 $ BB: int  2 8 6
 - attr(*, "na.action")=Class 'omit'  Named int [1:3] 2 4 6
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "2" "4" "6"
> 
> 
> str(mydf[complete.cases(mydf),])
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ AA: int  2 6 9
 $ BB: int  2 8 6
> 
> identical(na.omit(mydf), mydf[complete.cases(mydf),])
[1] FALSE
```

Are there any situations where one or the other should be used or effectively they are the same?

Comment: Presumably if you wanted to retain information about the omitted observations, i.e. what is given in the `na.action` attribute. Or the fact that `complete.cases` returns a logical vector means you could do something like `mydf[complete.cases(mydf[,1]),]` if you were only concerned with `NA` values in the first column.

Comment: Two good reasons. This could be an answer rather than just a comment.

Comment: if u assign the results to variables, they will be identical.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is true that `na.omit` and `complete.cases` are functionally the same when `complete.cases` is applied to all columns of your object (e.g. `data.frame`):

```
R> all.equal(na.omit(mydf),mydf[complete.cases(mydf),],check.attributes=F)
[1] TRUE
```

But I see two fundamental differences between these two functions (there may very well be additional differences). First, `na.omit` adds an `na.action` attribute to the object, providing information about how the data was modified WRT missing values. I imagine a trivial use case for this as something like:

```
foo <- function(data) {
  data <- na.omit(data)
  n <- length(attributes(na.omit(data))$row.names)
  message(sprintf("Note: %i rows removed due to missing values.",n))
  # do something with data
}
##
R> foo(mydf)
Note: 3 rows removed due to missing values.
```

where we provide the user with some relevant information. I'm sure a more creative person could (and probably has) find (found) better uses of the `na.action` attribute, but you get the point.

Second, `complete.cases` allows for *partial* manipulation of missing values, e.g.

```
R> mydf[complete.cases(mydf[,1]),]
  AA BB
1  2  2
3  6  8
4  5 NA
5  9  6
```

Depending on what your variables represent, you may feel comfortable imputing values for column `BB`, but not for column `AA`, so using `complete.cases` like this allows you finer control.